# Groovy script for test steps in SoapUI

Tags: php, groovy, soapui

In SoapUI (Pro version) I have 12 test steps:

1. `GET` request
2. Groovy script witch get `total` value from response from the previous step
3. Properties
4. Properties transfer
5. `POST` request 1
6. `POST` request 2
7. `POST` request 3
8. `POST` request 4
9. `POST` request 5
10. `POST` request 6
11. `POST` request 7
12. `POST` request 8

All `POST` requests have `ID` parameters.

**Question:**

How to write a Groovy script like this or maybe another decision way:

```
if total = 8 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 1,POST 2 = 1,POST 3 = 1,POST 4 = 1,POST 5 = 1,POST 6 = 1,POST 7 = 1,POST 8 = 1
if total = 7 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 2,POST 2 = 1,POST 3 = 1,POST 4 = 1,POST 5 = 1,POST 6 = 1,POST 7 = 1
if total = 6 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 2,POST 2 = 2,POST 3 = 1,POST 4 = 1,POST 5 = 1,POST 6 = 1
if total = 5 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 2,POST 2 = 2,POST 3 = 2,POST 4 = 1,POST 5 = 1
if total = 4 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 2,POST 2 = 2,POST 3 = 2,POST 4 = 2
if total = 3 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 3,POST 2 = 3,POST 3 = 2
if total = 2 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 4,POST 2 = 4
if total = 1 then set ID parameters of POST 1 = 8
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the following in the groovy [step 2]

```
def totalPostSteps = 8
def totalFromResponse = 7 //map the one you got from prev response
def postIdArray = new int[totalPostSteps]
def index = 0
1.upto (totalPostSteps,
{
    postIdArray[index]+=1;
    index = index==totalFromResponse-1?0:index+1
})
//log.info postIdArray.toString()
postIdArray.eachWithIndex{num, idx ->
     def numString = num!=0?num.toString():""
     //The next step will create/update properties in TestCase custom properties and u can map these directly to your POST requests
     //OR You can set these directly to step3 and continue with step 4
     testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdForPost_"+(idx+1), numString)
   }
```

Comment: your script result every time is different and approximately looks like this - I@3bb633cd or I@52c6035 or I@47a007e77 and so on

Comment: Oh. I change something and its work. Thank you. I change testRunner.testCase.setPropertyValue("IdForPost_"+(idx+1), numString) to  testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("Properties").setPropertyValue("IdForPost"+(idx+1), numString)